# C# Sql Client: ALTER Table doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, alter-table

I have a code that is used to add some lines to `SQL` but it won't work. `Select` and `Delete` are working but not the `ALTER TABLE` command.

If I copy and paste just my console output into `Microsoft Management Sql Query`, it works. (`tmp1` gets filled with some Name, `tmp2` gets filled for Example CHAR(50))

Edit: I dont get any Error, in the logs of my SQL server i dont see any command called "Alter" to be excuted.

```
 string tmp1, tmp2;
 tmp1 = addfrm.getTableName();
 tmp2 = addfrm.getType();

 string constring = @"Data Source=" + adr + ";Initial Catalog=" + dat + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + pwd;
 try
 {
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
     {
         string tmp = @"ALTER TABLE " + tbl + " ADD " + tmp1 + " " + tmp2;
         Console.WriteLine("Mein Befehl lautet: " + tmp);

         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(tmp, con))
         {
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
             {
             }
         }
     }
 }

 catch (SqlException) 
 { 
     MessageBox.Show("Fehler"); 
 }
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Post your error as well.

Comment: This command sounds like you are trying to add some columns to the table not to add lines.

Comment: You never executed SQL Query to database. Use `ExecuteNonQuery` on `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Make sure your application have a permission to alter the table and please post error message as comment above suggested.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever let me edit back to `SQL`

Answer (score 1):

You don't send SQL query to database. Use ExecuteNonQuery on SqlCommand. Instead of:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(tmp, con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {

    }
}
```

use

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(tmp, con))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Adapter will not execute query until `adapter.Fill` is called.

Comment: Can you also explain why it will not work with `SqlDataAdapter`. Is there any changes can be done, so that it works with `SqlDataAdapter `

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter` is intended to work with CRUD operations. No need to use it when DDL is performed.

Comment: It dosent do anything for me. I dont get any errors or Exception.

Comment: What do you expect as return value? `ALTER TABLE [Tab] ADD [Col] [Type]` syntax just adds column. No rows are returned.

Comment: No, it should just add it but it wont do it. Only over sql management with same command it works. After he is finished with adding he starts the BindGrid Method where he gets the table out database and binds it again on the datagriedview.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the values properly. Try this it should work.

```
string tmp1, tmp2;
                tmp1 = addfrm.getTableName();
                tmp2 = addfrm.getType();

                string constring = @"Data Source=" + adr + ";Initial Catalog=" + dat + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + pwd;
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
                    {
                        string tmp = @"UPDATE TABLE " + tbl + " SET Col1 = '" + temp1 +"',Col2='" + tmp2 +"'";

                        Console.WriteLine("Mein Befehl lautet: " + tmp);

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(tmp, con))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException) { MessageBox.Show("Fehler"); }
```

Comment: That didnt worked :/ same result for me (you forget + and wrote temp, i fixed that hope thats okay)

Comment: should be UPDATE  rather than alter i have updated the answer please check now.

Comment: Now he has some problems with ur Excute NonQuerry. The programm stops with error that the connections is still closed.
I tried to open it with con.Open(); and closed it afer the sqlnonquerry but that i get a SQL Exception with "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" in System.Data.dll.

Answer (score 0):

i just avoided it now with Fill. Its bit messy but ok. Thanks to Pawel who said it.

```
                            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                        }
```